# Spring boot does not add record to MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot

[MacOS Big Sur]
I am trying to create a hybrid system database using Spring, MongoDB and PostgreSQL. I have implemented nothing for the PSQL, but I have done everything perfectly for the MongoDB. The issue is that it does not add any record to the MongoDB (v4.4). Not even the LiveEventDB is added. Maybe because it is the fact that Spring does not find the repository file
I start the MongoServer by **brew services start mongodb-community**.
I run then the project on the Intellij editor and the log is fine. Everything, except this, I think:

> Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 3 ms. Found 0 MongoDB repository interfaces.

Although I have created a repository interface java file.

the structure is:
[The project package structure]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCT1a.png

----FILES----

**application.properties**

```
server.port = 8080
spring.data.mongodb.database=LiveEventsDB
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
```

**DBRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface DBRepository extends MongoRepository<LiveEvents, String> {
}
```

**LiveEvents.java**

```
@Document(collation = "LiveEvents")
public class LiveEvents {

    @Id
    private String rowID;

    @Indexed(direction = IndexDirection.ASCENDING)
    private Integer EID;
...
```

**DBAdder.java**

```
@Component
public class DBAdder implements CommandLineRunner {

//    private LiveEvents liveEvents;
    private DBDriver DBdriver;

    public DBAdder(DBDriver dbDriver) {
        this.DBdriver = dbDriver;
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        LiveEvents liveEvents = new LiveEvents(
                1,
                new FormTemplates[]{FormTemplates.SLIDER_FORM, FormTemplates.COMMENT_BLOCK_FORM}
        );

        this.DBdriver.deleteAll();

        this.DBdriver.save(liveEvents);
    }
}
```

**DBController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/LiveEvents")
public class DBController {

    private DBDriver driver;

    public DBController(DBDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    @GetMapping("/all")
    public List<LiveEvents> getAll(){
        List<LiveEvents> events = this.driver.findAll();
        return events;
    }
}
```

Forgot to add this:

**Main app**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"uk.co.group35.app.events.controllers"}, mongoTemplateRef="DBDriver")
public class LiveFeedbackApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LiveFeedbackApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**POM.XML**

```
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: Please share a snippet of your pom.xml with sping-boot dependencies.

Comment: @SergVasylchak, Posted in the main question now. Thanks

Comment: `, mongoTemplateRef="DBDriver"` remove this from your `@EnableMongoRepositories`. I'm not completely sure, but there may be a collision in bean namings for MongoTemplate and your MongoRepository

Comment: @SergVasylchak, Hmm... If I name DBDriver class to DBRepository will be more ok? I did that and nothing Happened

Comment: The purpose is to remove a possible collision, so yes, it should be ok. If nothing happened we are still missing why the repository does not get detected.

Comment: @SergVasylchak. Changed the Class names like this: DbRepository, DbAdder, DbController. Still nothing. It is not finding the Repository class

Comment: BTW, is the package structure in `main` package exactly the same as in `test`?

Comment: @SergVasylchak. Thank you for your tremendous help. I highly appreciate it. I worked super fine. I will take care of it. I am asking you now to post an answer to give you a tick for solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"uk.co.group35.app.events.controllers"}, mongoTemplateRef="DBDriver")
```

1. mongoTemplateRef is a bean name for org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate and it may collide with a bean name of your repository.
2. Review and maintain package struture carefully in case you use  `@EnableMongoRepositories#basePackages`. In case you `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class is in the root of package structure, you may ommit `basePackages` at all.

Answer (score -1):

Replace private DBDriver DBdriver; in Controller, DBAdder to
@Autowired
private final DBDriver DBdriver

Comment: Why? Single component's constructor is marked with `@Autowired` implicitly

Comment: you can read official how to https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mongodb/

Comment: @SergVasylchak yes you can write private final DBDriver DBdriver without annotation

Comment: Your point is more about dependency injection essentials in Spring. Both OP's and your approaches will work. But if you write `@Autowired private final Component component` it completely won't make any sense, as final field is going to be assigned in constructor only, whereas the annotataion is placed on field and is completely useless without `lombok.RequiredArgsConstructor` + lombok.copyableAnnotation+=Autowired in config. And even then it will stil be redunant for single-constructor component.

Comment: @DanMyrza, Can you please specify exactly the file that has to be changed?
I also forgot to add this: 

@ SpringBootApplication
@ EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"uk.co.group35.app.events.controllers"}, mongoTemplateRef="DBDriver")
public class LiveFeedbackApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(LiveFeedbackApplication.class, args);
    }

}

Comment: @TasteMyBomb SergVasylchak answered main class must be root package